# I cannot update the value when I fetch the user data from firebase database

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I can fetch the user data from the firebase, but I cannot input the user data to a global variable.

```
        Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID!).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary
        let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
        let userDigit = value?["lastDigit"] as? String ?? ""
        let userDate = value?["babyDate"] as? String ?? ""

        print(username)
        print(userDigit)
        print(userDate)


        self.user.userName = username
        self.user.userDigit = userDigit
        self.user.userDate = userDate


    }) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

            print(self.user.userName)
            print(self.user.userDigit)
            print(self.user.userDate)
```

From the above code, I can see the username, userDigit, userDate, however, after i input the data into user class that contains 3 string variables, i cannot print the user class value.

To be specific,
print(self.user.userName)
this code returns nil.

How can I input the data?

Comment: have you initialized the `user` object?

Comment: Yeah i did such as, var user = User()

Answer (score 1):

The value of `self.user.userName` is `nil` because you're calling it outside the observer closure.
Printing a value after assigning in a closure doesn't guarantee that it will be available immediately afterwards.
Because the closure of `observeSingleEvent` gets called after the data is fetched from firebase.
You should modify your logic and try to access the value of `user` after the data has successfully been fetched from firebase.
below is a sample code that might help you understand the concept:

```
func getUser(with userID: String, completion: @escaping ((_ user: User) -> Void)) {
    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(userID).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        // Get user value
        let value = snapshot.value as? [String: Any]
        let username = value?["username"] as? String ?? ""
        let userDigit = value?["lastDigit"] as? String ?? ""
        let userDate = value?["babyDate"] as? String ?? ""

        var user = User()
        user.userName = username
        user.userDigit = userDigit
        user.userDate = userDate

        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            completion(user)
        }
    }
}
```

In the above method, we fetch data from firebase and return it inside a closure of our own once the data is available.
and then you call the above function like this:

```
self.getUser(with: userID!) { (user) in
   // the user object inside the closure will be available after fetching data from firebase
   // the user object can even be assigned to a global property
    self.globalUser = user
    print(self.globalUser.userName)
    print(self.globalUser.userDigit)
    print(self.globalUser.userDate)
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello, I do appreciate your help! But I was just wondering if there is a way that I can input user name to a global variable? To be specific,
`var globalUser = User()`
`self.getUser(with: userID!) { (user) in
globalUser = user
}`
Still globalUser is a nil object

Comment: Yes you can do. but `globalUser` will not be `nil` after the control reaches the closure in `getUser`. i've updated the answer accordingly